# Can't change txt files to open with anything but WordPad

Tags: windows-10, wordpad, xls

I want to change txt files to open with a specific .xls  it used to work but for some reason now it won't save anymore when I set the .xls program as the default.

It's a serious pain to have to open each txt manually and change it to xls. I want them to just all open with this spreadsheet program instead of WordPad again.

I have Windows 10 x64.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue caused by a Windows update released on October 9th, 2018 ([KB4462919](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/4462919/windows-10-update-kb4462919)).  It was fixed in another update released today, November 27th, 2018 ([KB4467682](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/4467682/windows-10-update-kb4467682)).

> Addresses an issue that prevents some users from setting Win32 program defaults for certain app and file type combinations using the Open with… command or Settings > Apps > Default apps.